# (До тех пор, пока) или (до тех пор, пока не)

Tags: фразеология

Собственно, вопрос возник из-за крутящейся в голове строчки из песни Александра Городницкого:

И жить еще надежде
До той поры пока
Атланты небо держат
На каменных руках.

В большинстве источников (как и в приведенном фрагменте) ещё и запятая пропущена перед "пока" во второй строчке, но вопрос не о ней.
Вопрос вот о чём. Мне всегда казалось, что после "до той поры, пока" обязательно должна быть частица "не". Понятно, что "та пора" должна быть ограничена по времени и заканчиваться при наступлении какого-то события. Соответственно, пока событие не наступило, "та пора" продолжается.
Но может ли "пора" длиться, пока действует некое условие? Как в приведённом отрывке. Тогда частица "не" не потребуется.
И есть ли разница между "до той поры" и "до тех пор" по отношению к необходимости применения частицы "не"?

Comment: Прошу прощения за текст в виде каши. Движок сайта сам убрал переводы на новую строку. Может, потому, что пишу в мобильном браузере?

Comment: И жить еще надежде До той поры, пока **НЕ** Атланты небо держат... Так?! Непонятно.

Comment: @РоманБабаев Чтобы сделать перевод строки, нужно поставить в конце строки два пробела.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Имеется в виду "До той поры, пока атланты не бросят небо".

Comment: @grizzly Благодарю за подсказку. Я здесь новичок и ещё не освоился.   Не посоветуете, где прочесть о таких моментах? У меня и другие вопросы по работе с сайтом есть.. 2-минутный входной тур я прошёл, но там подробностей нет.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Да, я имел в виду именно то, что сказали grizzly и - ниже - Alex_ander. Просто написал длинно и сумбурно.

Comment: @РоманБабаев [Здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) можно посмотреть основные способы форматирования. Там, правда, не всё точно с переводом, но по примерам легко догадаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, почему Alex_under ограничился комментарием. Важно отметить, что выражение "до той поры, пока" требует описать "ту пору" (то есть будущее время, **до момента наступления которого** мы имеем то, что описано, а с его приходом потеряем) с добавлением частицы *не*. Откроем Нацкорпус.

> Но замкнутость брала власть над ним первое время ― **до той поры, пока не проходило** беспокойство и неизвестное делалось знакомым, а пережитое― обычным. [Олег Павлов. Карагандинские девятины, или Повесть последних дней // «Октябрь», 2001]
>
> Напротив, сам рабочий, обладая достаточно высоким профессиональным и непрофессиональным кругозором и природной совестливостью (а таких было немало **до той поры, пока** именем рабочего класса **не стали** твориться преступления), мог приближаться к тому, что мы называем общей интеллигентностью. [Дмитрий Лихачев. О русской интеллигенции (1993)]
>
> Михайлов же продолжает своё ― тихое и скромное, ненавязчивое вползание: состояние "я тебе, ты мне" не так уж и сложно, однако только **до той поры, пока оно не переходит** в состояние незаметной зависимости. [Владимир Маканин. Отдушина (1977)]

Answer (score 1):

ПОКА II. союз. **В то время как; до того времени как.** П. сын учится, надо ему помочь. П. солнце не взойдёт, на траве лежит иней.

***И жить еще надежде До той поры, пока Атланты небо держат На каменных руках.***

Здесь **одновременные события**: живет надежда и атланты держат небо.

Другой вариант **с тем же смыслом:** надежда живет, пока не перестанут держать.

Но ***держать*** и ***не перестать держать*** – это одно и то же.

**Примечание**. Союз ПОКА может выражать разновременность: Пока (к тому времени как) приехала полиция, все уже разбежались.

Answer (score 0):

Надежде жить, пока живы атланты, - где тут место отрицанию?

У автора:

> И жить ещё надежде
>   До той поры, пока
>   Атланты небо держат
>   На каменных руках.

Мы пели её на уроках пения (были такие) в третьем классе.

Пора ограничивается способностью к небодержанию атлантов. Вот если НЕ справятся, тогда НЕ жить.

Comment: Место отрицанию _есть_, хотя и не в предложенной форме, конечно. Должно было бы быть "до той поры, пока _не перестанут_ держать" - с наступлением "поры", до которой надежда жива, последняя умирает. Либо не должно быть "той поры" (просто "пока" работает правильно). Можно только списать всё на "поэтическую вольность".

Comment: @Alex_ander Это ответ, а не комментарий. Если оформите как ответ, он будет  заметней читателям.